# @MappedSuperclass no args constructor in Kotlin

Tags: hibernate, kotlin, jpa

I have configured the kotlin jpa plugin in order to get default constructors generated for entities but it doesn't seem to be working with inherited classes. Example:

```
plugins {
    kotlin("plugin.jpa") version "1.7.20"
}
```

```
@MappedSuperclass
class BaseEntity(
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    var id: Long,
)
```

```
@Entity
class YearEntity(
    @Column(name = "value", nullable = false)
    var value: String? = null,
) : BaseEntity()
```

This fails to compile because it says that BaseEntity doesn't have a default constructor.
What am i missing?

Comment: @xerx593 but the whole point of the jpa plugin is to avoid having to create a default constructor. And i don't want to make id nullable, because it's not.

Comment: I wonder if there's another error in there. `BaseEntity.id` should be `Long?` as hibernate will populate the value after the entity is stored in the db.

Comment: Why not to use the data class provided by kotlin ? any specific reason ?

Answer (score 1):

We can't call the zero-argument constructor directly as it is synthetic

From the No-arg plugin doc - [No-arg compiler plugin](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/no-arg-plugin.html)﻿

> The generated constructor is synthetic so it can't be directly called from Java or Kotlin, but it can be called using reflection.